# How to count days between two date cutoffs in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel workbook that looks like this

```
Year Date   Was the office open?
2016-01-01  Y
2016-01-02  Y
2016-01-03  N
2016-01-04  N
2016-01-05  N
2016-01-06  Y
2016-01-07  Y
2016-01-08  Y
2016-01-09  Y
2016-01-10  Y
2016-01-11  N
2016-01-12  Y
2016-01-13  Y
2016-01-14  Y
2016-01-15  Y
2016-01-16  N
2016-01-17  Y
2016-01-18  Y
2016-01-19  Y
2016-01-20  Y
2016-01-21  Y
2016-01-22  Y
2016-01-23  Y
2016-01-24  Y
2016-01-25  Y
2016-01-26  Y
2016-01-27  N
2016-01-28  Y
2016-01-29  Y
2016-01-30  Y
2016-01-31  Y
2016-02-01  Y
2016-02-02  Y
```

I have a second spreadsheet in the workbook that looks like this

```
Period Cutoff Dates
2016-01-01
2016-01-06
2016-01-12
2016-01-16
2016-01-27
2016-02-02
```

What I want is a sort of vlookup and count based on the Y/N that tells me the number of days the office was open in the period based on a diff of the date (or first date) and the prior date. I want to see this

```
Year Date   Was the office open?    Days office was open in the period
2016-01-01  Y   
2016-01-02  Y   
2016-01-03  N   
2016-01-04  N   
2016-01-05  N   Count the number of 'Y' between 2016-01-01 and 2016-01-06 less 1 day, show 2 in the 3rd column
2016-01-06  Y   
2016-01-07  Y   
2016-01-08  Y   
2016-01-09  Y    
2016-01-10  Y   
2016-01-11  N   Count the number of 'Y' between 2016-01-06 and 2016-01-12 less 1 day, show 5 in the 3rd column
2016-01-12  Y   
2016-01-13  Y   
2016-01-14  Y   
2016-01-15  Y   Count the number of 'Y' between 2016-01-12 and 2016-01-16 less 1 day, show 4 in the 3rd column
2016-01-16  N   
2016-01-17  Y   
2016-01-18  Y   
2016-01-19  Y   
2016-01-20  Y   
2016-01-21  Y   
2016-01-22  Y   
2016-01-23  Y   
2016-01-24  Y   
2016-01-25  Y   
2016-01-26  Y   Count the number of 'Y' between 2016-01-16 and 2016-01-27 less 1 day, show 10 in the 3rd column
2016-01-27  N   
2016-01-28  Y   
2016-01-29  Y   
2016-01-30  Y   
2016-01-31  Y   
2016-02-01  Y   
2016-02-02  Y   Count the number of 'Y' between 2016-01-27 and 2016-02-02, show 6 in the 3rd column
```

This should be easy. I just cannot get there. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you
JM

Comment: Just went through your history, if an answer helped and did what was asked you should mark it as correct by hitting the green check mark by the answer.  I would go back through your history and mark the correct answer, it will encourage others to help in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your solution - spot on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment about marking the question as an answer. Honestly I didn't appreciate that if I clicked on the arrow, it was marked as an answer. It makes sense now. I have marked your answer as the answer too. Much appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet25!$A:$A,Sheet24!A2+1),COUNTIFS($A:$A,">=" & INDEX(Sheet25!$A:$A,MATCH(Sheet24!A2,Sheet25!$A:$A)),$A:$A,"<="&INDEX(Sheet25!$A:$A,MATCH(Sheet24!A2,Sheet25!$A:$A)+1)-1,$B:$B,"Y"),"")
```

Change the Sheet25 to your sheet name with the short list.

Put in C2 and copy down.

[image: ![enter image description here]